# Expanding face geometry even offset outside

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to expand face geometry equal to same size like inset but towards outside.

I have tried to inset with outer option, but it is not expanding as I expected working on other dimension of the geometry.

Likewise, I could not use extrude along normal options.

Insetting and scaling -1 could work, but I am not sure how to apply scale on inset.

[image: Problem]

Comment: Extrude face edges and scale about face center ?

Comment: you can extrude your plane to give it thickness, it will give a cube, then extrude the sides of the cube along normals

Comment: If you've just got a simple plane, scale it to the dimension you want the 'outset' and then inset back so that the new face is where the old one was will work if you don't need the original face exactly where it was

Comment: Thank you. All @moonboots solution is working for me, but I cannot mark as solved. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with a simple plane, but you can extrude your plane to give it thickness, it will give a cube, extrude the sides of the cube along normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>), delete the top to get a simple plane.